# How to mutate a list of custom objects in GraphQL for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, mutation

Using [GraphQL for .NET](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet), I would like to replace the collection of Foo with a new collection.

Given this server-side code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Foo[] Foos { get; private set; }

    public Foo[] UpdateFoos(Foo[] foos)
    {
        Foos = foos;
        return Foos;
    }
}

public class MutationSchema : Schema
{
    public MutationSchema()
    {
        Query = new MutationQuery();
        Mutation = new MutationChange();
    }
}

public class FooType : ObjectGraphType
{
    public FooType()
    {
        Name = "IndividualFoo";
        Field<StringGraphType>("name");
    }
}

public class FoosType : ObjectGraphType<ListGraphType<FooType>>
{
    public FoosType()
    {
        Name = "ListOfFoo";
        Field<ListGraphType<FooType>>("foos");
    }
}

public class FoosInput : InputObjectGraphType
{
    public FoosInput()
    {
        Name = "InputForManyFoo";
        Field<ListGraphType<FooInput>>("foos");
        Field<ListGraphType<FooType>>("foosResult");
    }
}

public class FooInput : InputObjectGraphType
{
    public FooInput()
    {
        Name = "InputForSingleFoo";
        Field<StringGraphType>("name");
    }
}

public class MutationQuery : ObjectGraphType
{
    public MutationQuery()
    {
        Name = "Query";
        Field<FoosType>("queryAllFoos");
    }
}

public class MutationChange : ObjectGraphType
{
    public MutationChange()
    {
        Name = "Mutation";

        Field<FoosInput>(
            "updateAllFoos",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(
                new QueryArgument<FoosInput>
                {
                    Name = "updateFoosQueryArgument"
                }
            ),
            resolve: context =>
            {
                var root = context.Source as Root;
                var change = context.GetArgument<Foo[]>("updateFoosQueryArgument");
                // TODO: update collection e.g. return root.UpdateFoos(change);
                return change;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

When I run the mutation query:

```
mutation M {
    fooCollection: updateAllFoos(updateFoosQueryArgument: {
        foos: [
            {name: "First Foo"},
            {name: "Second Foo"}
        ]}) {
        foosResult
    }
}
```

Then I get the following error:

```
{GraphQL.Validation.ValidationError: Cannot query field "foosResult" on type "InputForManyFoo". Did you mean "foosResult"?}
```

I'm using the [latest version of GraphQL for .NET](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/commit/b77e508fb92158e0432570cab3b576d30551e855) at the time of writing.

What am I missing?

---

**Working Example:** [How to mutate a list of custom objects in GraphQL for .NET](https://gist.github.com/DanielRobinsonSoftware/9ef4aa2834f2c912b5a3d4ef63ba6188)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer from Gitter.

Make an `ObjectGraphType` for the result.  Notice that the “shape” of the object that is returned from resolve matches the “shape” of the graph type.

```
public class FoosResultType : ObjectGraphType
{
    public FoosResultType()
    {
        Field<ListGraphType<FooType>>("foosResult");
    }
}

public class FoosResult
{
    public IEnumerable<Foo> FoosResult { get;set; }
}

public class MutationChange : ObjectGraphType
{
    public MutationChange()
    {
        Name = "Mutation";

        Field<FoosResultType>(
            "updateAllFoos",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(
                new QueryArgument<ListGraphType<FooInput>>
                {
                    Name = "updateFoosQueryArgument"
                }
            ),
            resolve: context =>
            {
                var root = context.Source as Root;
                var change = context.GetArgument<List<Foo>>("updateFoosQueryArgument");
                // TODO: update collection e.g. return root.UpdateFoos(change);
                return new FoosResult { FoosResult = change };
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And updated mutation:

```
mutation M {
    fooCollection: updateAllFoos(updateFoosQueryArgument: [
          {name: "First Foo"},
          {name: "Second Foo"}
        ]) {
        foosResult {
          name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help Joe! 

I will revisit on Monday morning and make sure it works. It's past validation now but it falls over during execution on the GetArgument line.  

{GraphQL.Validation.ValidationError: Argument "updateFoosQueryArgument" has invalid value {foos: [{name: "First Foo"}, {name: "Second Foo"}]}.
In field "foos": Unknown field.}

Comment: I'll try alternatives to Foo[] (IEnumerable etc)

Comment: I updated the mutation - I had forgotten to change `updateFoosQueryArgument` in the mutation to just be a list.

Comment: An array doesn't work - changed context.GetArgument<Foo[]>("updateFoosQueryArgument"); to context.GetArgument<List<Foo>>("updateFoosQueryArgument");