# GraphQL returns the error message "Cannot query field..." when I try to get all records

Tags: php, laravel, graphql

I have installed a package [rebing/graphql-laravel](https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel) version 5.1.4. When I'm trying to pass query through postman for getting all Products I'm getting the error

`"Cannot query field \"products\" on type \"Query\". Did you mean \"product\"?"`

My structure of folders

[image]

My ProductQuery.php

```
namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use App\Models\Product;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Query;

class ProductQuery extends Query
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'product',
        'description' => 'A query'
    ];

    /**
     * Return type for these query
     * @return Type
     */
    public function type(): Type
    {
        return GraphQL::type('Product');
    }

    /**
     * Passed arguments for this query
     * @return array
     */
    public function args(): array
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'name' => 'slug',
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'rules' => ['required']
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Resolve Query to get pass an information
     * @param mixed $root
     * @param array $args
     * @return Product
     */
    public function resolve($root, array $args): Product
    {
        return Product::where('slug', $args['slug'])->first();
    }
}
```

My ProductsQuery.php

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use App\Models\Product;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Query;

class ProductsQuery extends Query
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'products',
    ];


    public function type(): Type
    {
        return Type::listOf(GraphQL::type('Product'));
    }


    public function resolve($root, $args)
    {
        return Product::all();
    }
}
```

My ProductType.php

```
<?php
namespace App\GraphQL\Types;

use App\Models\Product;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Type as GraphQLType;

class ProductType extends GraphQLType
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Product',
        'description' => 'A type',
        'model' => Product::class
    ];

    public function fields(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::int()),
                'description' => 'Product Id'
            ],
            'name' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'Product Name'
            ],
            'type' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'Product Type'
            ],
            'slug' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'Product Slug'
            ],
            'sku' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'Product SKU'
            ],
            'barcode' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'Product Barcode'
            ],
            'description' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'Product Description'
            ],
            'status' => [
                'type' => Type::boolean(),
                'description' => 'Product Status'
            ],
            'in_stock' => [
                'type' => Type::boolean(),
                'description' => 'Product In Stock'
            ],
            'track_stock' => [
                'type' => Type::boolean(),
                'description' => 'Product Track Stock'
            ],
            'is_taxable' => [
                'type' => Type::boolean(),
                'description' => 'Product Is Taxable'
            ],
            'qty' => [
                'type' => Type::float(),
                'description' => 'Product Qty'
            ],
            'price' => [
                'type' => Type::float(),
                'description' => 'Product Price'
            ],
            'cost_price' => [
                'type' => Type::float(),
                'description' => 'Product Cost Price'
            ],
            'weight' => [
                'type' => Type::float(),
                'description' => 'Product Weight'
            ],
            'height' => [
                'type' => Type::float(),
                'description' => 'Product Height'
            ],
            'length' => [
                'type' => Type::float(),
                'description' => 'Product Length'
            ],
            'width' => [
                'type' => Type::float(),
                'description' => 'Product Width'
            ],
            'meta_title' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'Product Meta Title'
            ],
            'meta_description' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'Product Meta Description'
            ],
            'created_at' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'Product Created At'
            ],
            'updated_at' => [
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'description' => 'Product Updated At'
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

My config graphql.php

```
    'schemas' => [
        'default' => [
            'query' => [
                'product' => App\GraphQL\Queries\ProductQuery::class,
                'products' => App\GraphQL\Queries\ProductsQuery::class
            ],
            'mutation' => [
            ],
            'middleware' => [],
            'method' => ['get', 'post'],
        ],
    ],

    'types' => [
        'Product' => App\GraphQL\Types\ProductType::class,
    ]
```

I try to make a request through the postman

[image]

However, when I'm trying to receive the product through "slug" it works well. I'm stuck with my problem. It seems all right but probably I something missing. I am new in graphql and I need a push in the right direction :) Thanks so much.

**Updated**: I know the problem not in the cache. After any changes, I do  `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: is it working for product query?

Comment: @AkashSarode yes, it works for a product by slug.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
query {
products {
    id
    name
    ...
}}
```

instead of

```
{
products {
   id
   name
   ...
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same issue but with .Net Gql and angular, essentially the issue is in the result type that you are trying to query. Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051523/how-to-mutate-a-list-of-custom-objects-in-graphql-for-net).

I hope this help you. Anyway, update your status to check if the issue continue.

Cheers!